# DB2 AS/400 iseries Use alias in where clause

Tags: sql, db2, ibm-midrange

I'm trying to use the alias of a column in the where clause. for example:

```
SELECT col1 AS alias1, col2 + col3 as sums 
FROM my_table
WHERE sums > 10
```

But then I get an error message saying:

> Column sums not in specified tables.

Is there anyway I can do this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you really want to use alias in `WHERE`, not the column itself, you can do it with derived table :

```
SELECT a.* 
FROM
(
  SELECT lmITNO AS Item_Number, lmBANO AS Lot, lmSTAS AS Status, 
  lmRORN AS Order_Number 
  FROM MVXJDTA.MILOMA 
) a
WHERE a.Status = 'CCC'
....
```

Comment: @RamazanPolat: Where do you see Fetch First N Rows in the question ?   And why do you think it would not work?

Comment: I believe that comment was meant for another question and I somehow posted it under this question. Deleted.

Answer (score 7):

The [where-clause](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzwhereclause.htm) is processed before the [select-clause](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzselectclause.htm) in a statement:

> *The WHERE clause specifies an intermediate result table that consists of those rows of R for which the search-condition is true. R is the result of the FROM clause of the statement.*

Re-write the **where-clause** to reference the actual column name:

```
...
WHERE A.lmSTAS = 'CCC'
...
```

A [common-table-expression](http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/iseries/v7r1m0/topic/db2/rbafzcomtexp.htm) can be used to pre-process the **select-clause**.  For example:

```
WITH A AS (SELECT 
    lmITNO AS Item_Number, 
    lmBANO AS Lot, 
    lmSTAS AS Status, 
    lmRORN AS Order_Number 
FROM MVXJDTA.MILOMA)
SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE A.Status = 'CCC'
FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY
```

The columns in a **CTE** can also be renamed by listing them after the **table-identifier**.  For example:

```
WITH A (Item_Number, Lot, Status, Order_Number)
AS (SELECT 
    lmITNO, 
    lmBANO, 
    lmSTAS, 
    lmRORN
FROM MVXJDTA.MILOMA)
SELECT A.* FROM A WHERE A.Status = 'CCC'
FETCH FIRST 1000 ROWS ONLY
```